# HDFS NFS startup error: "ERROR portmap.Portmap: Failed to start the server... ChannelException: Failed to bind"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Attempting to use / startup HDFS NFS following the [docs](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/data-storage/content/start_and_verify_the_nfs_gateway_service.html), but running into error when trying to set up the NFS service starting the `hadoop portmap` service:

```sh
[root@HW02 hdfs]# service rpcbind stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop rpcbind.service
Warning: Stopping rpcbind.service, but it can still be activated by:
  rpcbind.socket
[root@HW02 hdfs]#
[root@HW02 hdfs]#
[root@HW02 hdfs]# hadoop portmap

WARNING: Use of this script to execute portmap is deprecated.

WARNING: Attempting to execute replacement "hdfs portmap" instead.

19/07/23 10:17:14 INFO portmap.Portmap: STARTUP_MSG:

/************************************************************

STARTUP_MSG: Starting Portmap

STARTUP_MSG: host = HW02.co.local/172.18.4.47

STARTUP_MSG: args = []

STARTUP_MSG: version = 3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78

STARTUP_MSG: classpath = /usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/conf:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.19.jar:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/lib/ranger-hdfs-plugin-shim-1.2.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/lib/jersey-servlet-1.19.jar:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/lib/ranger-plugin-classloader-1.2.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar:

...<many other jars>...

STARTUP_MSG: build = git@github.com:hortonworks/hadoop.git -r e4f82af51faec922b4804d0232a637422ec29e64; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2018-12-06T12:26Z

STARTUP_MSG: java = 1.8.0_112

************************************************************/

19/07/23 10:17:14 INFO portmap.Portmap: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]

19/07/23 10:17:14 ERROR portmap.Portmap: Failed to start the server. Cause:

org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:111

at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)

at org.apache.hadoop.portmap.Portmap.start(Portmap.java:122)

at org.apache.hadoop.portmap.Portmap.main(Portmap.java:65)

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)

at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)

at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)

at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)

at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)

at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)

at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391)

at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315)

at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)

at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)

at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

19/07/23 10:17:14 INFO portmap.Portmap: SHUTDOWN_MSG:

/************************************************************

SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down Portmap at HW02.co.local/172.18.4.47

************************************************************/
```

Not sure how to interpret any of the errors seen here, any debugging suggestions or solutions for what to do about this?

Comment: Are you using SLES 11 or RHEL 6.2?  If you're not then you should use the portmap which is included in your Linux distro and NOT run `hadoop portmap`.

Comment: @tk421 Should have specified, using Centos7. From the docs "Although NFS Gateway works with portmap included with most Linux distributions, you **must use the portmap included in the NFS Gateway package on some Linux systems such as SLES 11 and RHEL 6.2**." I took this to mean that I HAD TO run `hadoop portmap` from the HDP installation (since did *not* have SLES11 or RHEL6.2). Guess I misread the docs, so I suppose then that I would not stop the `rpcbind` service (and just ignore the `hadoop portmap` command)?

Comment: Correct.  I've setup Hadoop NFS before and I've never used `hadoop portmap` so I cannot vouch for it's reliability.  I've always used the existing portmap and had no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer while debugging another NFS gateway problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57228283/8236733

**TLDR**: nfs gateway service was already running (by default, apparently) and the service that I thought was blocking the hadoop nfs3 service (jsvc.exec) from starting was (I'm assuming) part of that service already running. The docs for setting up NFS Gateway for HDFS for HDP3.1 are not necessarily the best way to do it if you are already managing your cluster via ambari.